# ‘ltrunc’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c

I have problem with creating shared memory between two processes.
I getting this error, and I don't know what to do because I think a have all libraries included.

Log...

```
 g++ exc8.c -o exc8
 exc8.c: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
 exc8.c:29:37: error: ‘ltrunc’ was not declared in this scope
 size = ltrunc(fd, B_SIZE, SEEK_SET);
```

Code...

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <sys/mman.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define B_SIZE 4 

char* memory = new char[4];
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int size, fd; 
    char *buf; 
    char memory[4];
    fd = shm_open(memory, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0774);
    if (fd < -0) { 
        perror("open"); 
        exit(-1); 
    } 
    size = ltrunc(fd, B_SIZE, SEEK_SET);
    if(size < 0) {
        perror("trunc"); 
        exit(-1); 
    } 
    buf = (char *)mmap(0, B_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0); 
    if(buf == NULL) {
        perror("map"); 
        exit(-1); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: There is no standard system call named `ltrunc`. Where have you read/heard about it?

Comment: Also, while most of the code is C, there is some C++ in there. As well as you having a local variable shadowing a global. You also don't use `B_SIZE` everywhere it could be used, and in C, don't typecast functions returning `void*` (but since this is apparently not C, then you have to typecast).

Comment: I think you are looking for lseek.

Comment: - off_t ltrunc(int fdes, off_t offset, int whence) - return value of previously created memory segnent

Comment: this is example http://wklej.org/id/1172331/, sry for polish

Comment: google ltrunc, seems like it is a QNX or blackberry function. Not posix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where `ltrunc()` comes from, but
you can set the size of a shared memory object with `ftruncate()`:

```
if (ftruncate(fd, B_SIZE) == -1) {
    // Handle error
}
```

(from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/shm_open.html).

Answer (score 1):

`ltrunc` is not a standard function. It seems defined in [QNX](http://www.users.pjwstk.edu.pl/~jms/qnx/help/watcom/clibref/qnx/ltrunc.html) Platform using qcc as the compiler, which truncates a file at given position. Probably POSIX provides the `truncate()` and `ftruncate()` functions for the job.